# Load html page with properly javascript files

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two pages html (upload  page and insert page) with own javascript files. These two pages are the same with the javascript functions. The unique difference is that when I load the insert page it doesn't load from the server some information and when I load the upload page it ask to server some information. The others difference is the name of the button.

Is there a way in order to merge these two page and before to load the page to know its behavior (and to print the right button for instance and to set some global parameters in order to use properly the javascript function)? Maybe with a Ajax with the server? Or it is better to have the two page with own code that the difference is minimum?

The server is written in php.

For instance:

Upload page has green button and the insert page has blue button.

The javascript are more or less the same but in certain case there is some   difference. This difference can be manage by a if:

```
if(flag===true) do X
else do Y
```

I have to thought to maintain separately the two page but the code is redundant.

So I have thought this approach:

1. I don't load the page (I use an spinner loop) and I ask to server some information
2. By this information I show the
   button blue or green and set some variables

My answer is: It is better to maintain a redundant code or to use a different approach? And if it is better to use a difference approach which?

Comment: Everything mentioned is possible. Create test files to try various approaches out so you don't affect the live ones for now. Beyond that this whole question is far too broad without having some actual code to troubleshoot

Comment: Hi Lucas, would you please explain your question in more detail, right now it is not much clear, maybe try uploading your code. I would love to help.

Comment: charlietfl is correct and whether or not your pages are combined is really your choice however if you find that you are duplicating Javascript I would try to combine them into a single file. I gave you an upvote to get you out of negative in hopes you might provide some code so as someone can provide you with a solution and turn this question into a positive experience for all. Good luck.

Comment: @Mohi I have edited my question, it is not possibile to put my code because it is very very long. I only wish to know if there is a method in order to ask some information to the server before to load the page or something like that

Comment: @Mayhem50 Don't worry, I'm thinking how to do this in runtime

Comment: When you say redundant code do you mean it's not used at all or not used by the current page?

Comment: For redundant I means that I have file A with C1 C2 C3 (that are javascript files) and file B with C1s C2s C3s (that are javascript files). C1 and C1s are different for a console log or an alert. So the code of C1 and C1s are the same more or less. But file A uses C1 and file B use C1s but file A and file B are more or less the same (for instance the difference is a color of a button)

Comment: Lucas, according to me you should place your if else condition inside the server code and decide the response at server end instead of placing your condition at client end. By this you will be able to merge code on your sever end. So for instance, in your request send query parameters and generate response from sever on the basis of that query parameters.

Comment: I cannot do it because it is more or less a single page application so I need to do these operations inside the client.